# CREATE EVENT, Insert multple row in same time

Tags: mysql

for example, on the same day, in Loan table have more than 2 rows are expired, and i want insert 2 fines in Fine table.

I did:

```
CREATE EVENT test_event_insert_fine
ON SCHEDULE every 1 day
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO 
    IF (NOW()>=DATE_ADD(select date from loan, interval 3 day)) then
      insert into fine(price,date) values(100,NOW());
    END IF;
```

How can I insert multiple rows with only one "insert" according condition of "IF"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option that may be helpful:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE EVENT `test_event_insert_fine`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO
    BEGIN
        DECLARE `_NOW` DATETIME DEFAULT NOW();
        INSERT INTO `fine` (`price`, `date`)
        SELECT 100, `_NOW`
        FROM `loan`
        WHERE `_NOW` >= DATE_ADD(`date`, INTERVAL 3 DAY);
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```